# Converting VBScript to JavaScript for labelling in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, javascript, labeling, vbscript

I have a VB script used by ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop to label different types of streets based on vales present in a specific field. I am a novice at Python but VB and JavaScript are beyond me. I need this to be JavaScript for older version of ArcGIS. Here is the script in VB:

```
Function FindLabel ( [STREETNAME] )
' Extracts number from [STREETNAME]
' ---------------------------
  Dim sIn, sNew, i
  sIn = [STREETNAME]  ' input field value
  sNew = ""  'result

  i = 1

  ' check if char is numeric
  While i <= Len(sIn)    
    If IsNumeric(Mid(sIn, i, 1)) Then
      sNew = sNew & (Mid(sIn, i, 1))
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Wend

  FindLabel = sNew

End Function
```

Comment: Can you please clarify _I need this to be JavaScript for older version of ArcGIS_? What older version of ArcGIS do you mean? To my knowledge, ArcGIS Desktop doesn't support (and has never supported) JavaScript labelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through the answer to this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601997/how-to-approach-converting-vbscript-to-python-code

Break down the labeling script into its parts (variables, functions, etc.) and then write that in pseudo-code. Since you are not familiar with JavaScript syntax, the Esri Help is a good place to start: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000027000000